# Entity Framework Core - How to handle Related Entity Mapping and Saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, savechanges

I have two related entity which is one-to-many relationship like below:

```
class parent{
 public string parentName{get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<child> childs { get; set; }
}

class child{
  public string childName{get;set;}
  public parent parent{get;set;}
  ["ForeignKey"]
  public int parentId {get; set;}
}
/// View Model
class VMParent{
  public string parentName{get;set;}
  /// a string array contains child name
  public string[] childlist { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose my parent currently contains 2 child with name: (**apple, pear**), now I want to update it through web api to contain 3 child (**apple, orange, banana**), note here the **existed child pear is removed** and **2 new child(orange, banana) is added, here assume that orange is already existed in table child but banana is not, it should be considered as new entry to child table**, and I can get my updated model with childs name in a string array(**["apple", "orange", "banana"]**) from web api body View Model like:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string name, [FromBody]VMParent VMUpdateParent)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existingParent = await _context.Parents
                            .Include(t => t.childs)
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.parentName == name);

        existingParent.parentName = updateParent.parentName;

        var childsToBeUpdated = updateParent.childList; /// ["apple","orange","banana"]

        /// HOW TO HANDLE or REBUILD the relationship that can
        /// 1) remove child (pear) from existingParent
        /// 2) add child "banana" to Child table
        /// 3) add childs (orange and banana) to existingParent?
        ......

        _context.Parents.Update(existingParent);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new NoContentResult();
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Is there any "MERGE" statement like in SQL in Entity Framework Core? I am really looking forward to some more tutorials in real-world application with Entity Framework...

Comment: better you write in this way. You add a parentid column to child table as foreignkey and  you pass parent name and update all the children with where condition ( join on parent id with parent table)from child table to parentid set null

Comment: Thank you! I've added the foreign key column parentId in child table, but what exactly should I do next?

Comment: You should set parentid null or delete entry from child table

Comment: In order to do that I guess I would do following steps: 1) from my "existingParent" entity, map an array of childs' name(because "existingParent" entity would contain a list of "child" object not just name) 2) Use the mapped array to compare with my view model "VMUpdateParent" child name array to figure out that "pear" is the one needs to be removed and "orange, banana" are the ones need to be added 3) select single child entity by name equlas "pear" from child table, set "parentId" FK to be null 4) select each child entity by name "orange/banana" from child table, set "parentId" FK, correct?

Comment: It feels like the process is complex, is there any efficient way on doing that?

Comment: What exactly is `Teams` is that suppose to be parents?

Comment: @Johnny, sorry that was a typo, it should be `_context.Parent.Update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out one solution myself by using **AutoMapper** in between view model **VMUpdateParent** with existed model **existingParent** to *remove unnecessary child node and add new child node.*

However, if anyone has any improved or better solution, please feel free to share here. Thanks in advance!