# Select only one item from owned collection (EF core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Imagine that we have entity with owned collection and we want to select only one item from there by some condition. Is there any way to do it or I must load all collection?

Example:

```
class A {
    public ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public int SomeValue {get; set;}
}
```

And we want to get object with `SomeValue == 2`

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635812/entity-framework-core-linq-query-to-filter-related-entity ?

Comment: I think no. I just have collection of value objects and I want to retrieve some item from there by some condition that doesn't relate to main query

Comment: Maybe this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit#querying-related-entities ? (the 2nd sample)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. So, I think in my case it cannot be done. Thank you very much for helping C:

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the entire collection because you want to check a particular condition. Any one item from the collection can match the condition that why we have to traverse the entire collection.
By the way, you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/) to perform a conditional operation to make code more readable.

```
B.Where(condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bs.Where(t=>t.SomeValue == 2).First()